# script reference causes conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code 1 which executes with this in the head:

```
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then I have code 2 which goes by:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="livesearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem is that when I put the last reference (code 2) the first doesn't work anymore..
What am I doing wrong?

( for some reason code 2 doesnt react on jquery 1.7 )

Comment: why the hell are you including jquery once with version 1.7.1 and once with 1.4.3??

Comment: nope! sry man, you did not answer that - why do you even think this is/should be possible?

Comment: Yes I did: ( for some reason code 2 doesnt react on jquery 1.7 )

Comment: @Youss A less hackish solution than `.noConflict()` would probably be finding a substitute for `livesearch.js` that works with 1.7 or updating the library. Most libraries that build on jQuery are small enough that this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @Inerdial Thanks, I will try doing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is this : [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

> If necessary, we can free up the jQuery name as well by **passing true**
>   as an argument to the method. This is rarely necessary, and if we must
>   do this (for example, if we need to use multiple versions of the
>   jQuery library on the same page)

For example:

```
<script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript">
// now you alias the v1.7 jQuery to jQuery17
jQuery17 = jQuery.noConfict(true);
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript">
// now you alias the v1.4 jQuery to jQuery14
jQuery14 = jQuery.noConfict(true);
</script>
```

And put you two parts of code in different scopes.

```
(function($){
//put your codes here which need jQuery 1.7 version
.....
})(jQuery17);

(function($){
//put your codes here which need jQuery 1.4 version
.....
})(jQuery14);
```

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Hey man, don't you know you can do `jQuery.noConflict(true);`

Comment: Actually ... "I solved it by using true parameter in .noConflict(true) 
but it still gives problems with jquery ui and is not perfect"

Comment: and if you free up the name, how can you access different versions?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair `jQuery.noConflict` returns the `jQuery` self.

Comment: and how are you going to inject version 1.4.3 to live-search component, which obviously needs version 1.4.3?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

from your code.

actually you are including jquery once with 1.7.1 and once with 1.4.3. There's a solution with `jQuery.noConflict` - but have a look at [xdazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961203/57508)

EDIT:

So if the library, which your trying to include with `<script src="livesearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` won't work, it might not be implemented for version 1.7.1 - so please see the authors website/documentation for more information, for which jquery-framework version he/she did the implementation. If you know this, you **have to stick to this version**, unless the author realeses an update (although many components are written version-independent, but sometimes jquery brakes some interna).

Comment: Like I stated: ( for some reason code 2 doesnt react on jquery 1.7 )

Comment: @Youss just don't include jquery twice ... either go with 1.7.1 or with 1.4.3 - but a double-include with different version sucks!

Comment: If I go with one of them, one of the two codes wont work. Maybe there is an equivalent for jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js so it can go along with 1.4.3 ...

Comment: @Youss actually jqueryUI 1.8.13 should work with jquery 1.4.3 (according to http://jqueryui.com/, where it states: "Stable (1.8.17: jQuery 1.3.2+)")

Comment: Lets forget about two times jquery (just to make it simple..) Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/4az8f/ As you can see it wil work with 1.7 but not with 1.4 Can you explain to me why that is?

Comment: What the hell are you talking about! all the links are copy's of 1.7!

Comment: @Youss ah - just got it now ... you are doing the includes not the jsfiddle-way - haha. i will not support this kinda question, cuz it's too much effort changing the links - sry!

Comment: @downvoter: would be nice if you let me know the reason, so i can evaluate!

Comment: Even if you do it in that way it still doesnt work ( I think you are very weak..and a waste of time)