# how to solve the Jquery version conflicts

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

I have a website built in 2008, and i used many jquery plugins, those days it was jquery 1.3.

Now last week i was trying to upgrade to jquery 1.7 and when i do that, i had few issues.

**if i upgrade to the new version i have some plug-ins not working, 
so obvious solution is to make sure you use the latest plugins, ..
well it was not that simple, some plugins don't have a version for 
this jquery version.**

So i now have to upgrade the jquery but cant upgrade because of the plugins, 
and i cant use new plugins too because its too old..

So my questions is

**is there way to tell jquery to use this version(after including the both version)
and is there a way to tell the jquery or html page to use a version specified by me?**

Comment: Yes, by namespacing older jQuery versions in conjunction with [`jQuery.noConflict(true);`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: Check my answer of this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961120/script-reference-causes-conflict/8961203#8961203

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugin-that-needs-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugin-that-needs-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var newJQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true),
            oldJQuery = jQuery;

      (function ($) {

            // code that needs 1.4.2 goes here

}(newJQuery));

      (function ($) {

            // code that needs 1.2.6 goes here

}(oldJQuery));

      // code that needs oldJQuery and newJQuery can go here
</script>
```

The same question was asked here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-remove-jquery-version-conflict

Comment: If you want to run code on page load anyway, you can also do `newJQuery(function($) { ... });` and `oldJQuery(function($) { ... });`