# if statement dependent on jQuery().jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way of running a function depending on the version of jquery running?
Right now I have:

```
var jqVersion = jQuery().jquery;

if (jqVersion == '1.4.2') { 

    //jQuery 1.4.2 specific script here.

} else {

   //jQuery that works on rest of the site here

}
```

This works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome and IE the page gives an error for the code in the `else` block even if the condition is met and the `else` is unneeded. Cheers.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop'`
The .prop method is only used in the `else` block.

Comment: @acowley: so what is your actual question?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Are you writing a plugin?

Comment: The main site uses jQuery 1.7.2 except for a legacy application that uses 1.4.2. The script in the conditional for the legacy application is huge, and I don't have the resources to update it right now.

@zerkms Is there a better way of doing this given the constraints.

Comment: @acowley: `jQuery().jquery` is a correct way of doing that

Comment: @zerkms What about doing the conditional differently?

Comment: @acowley: differently to what? `jQuery().jquery` is a correct way of retrieving the version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your error is associated with `.prop()`, that was added in jQuery version 1.6 then you should just check to see if that method is available and act accordingly.

```
if (jQuery().prop) {
    // .prop() methods exists
}
```

or even just:

```
if (jQuery.fn.prop) {
    // .prop() methods exists
}
```

FYI, you can see what version any given jQuery feature was added [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/).

---

My recommendation is to check to see if the specific method you want is there as above.  But, if you feel you have to check versions, then you need to check greater than, not for equality.  As you already know, `jQuery().jQuery` contains the version as a string.  If you want to check for a version greater than some number, then you need to parse that string into numbers and compare to them.  Here's a function to do that:

```
jQuery.getVersionObject = function() {
    var versionStr = jQuery().jQuery;
    var matches = versionStr.match(/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/);
    var num = (matches[1] * 1000 * 1000) + (matches[2] * 1000) + (matches[3]);
    return ({major: matches[1], minor: matches[2], rev: matches[3]; num: num})
}

jQuery.checkMinVersion(major, minor, rev) {
    minor = minor || 0;
    rev = rev || 0;
    var num = (major * 1000 * 1000) + (minor * 1000) + rev;
    var version = jQuery.getVersionObject();
    return(version.num >= num);
}
```

Example usage:

```
if (jQuery.checkMinVersion(1, 6, 0)) {
    // jQuery version is 1.6.0 or higher
}
```

Comment: +1 I agree with most of your answer...why go through all that trouble parsing though? The version is stored as a string because, well, it *is*. A simple text comparison `version > "1.4.2"` would be fine, for example.

Comment: @nbrooks - text comparison of numbers only works if both strings have identical number of digits in every slot which is not guaranteed for the version string.  Feature testing is better.

Comment: Like I said, I agree feature testing is better, but you also provide code for checking version. I'm not sure that jQuery would ever not return three digits in the version but, in any case, that wouldn't make the comparison fail, since the most significant digs are to the right and any omission would be from the left...not a major point though, and I see where problems could arise if you weren't sure which sub-version a feature was added in or something

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Checking for the prop method is a much better way of doing things. It works well in all browsers now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @nbrooks - In `checkMinVersion()`, you can leave off the least significant version number of it isn't important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not write code depends on the jQuery version.

The most part of the code should be same, for some special part, test whether the property exists instead of using the version of jQuery.

***Example:***

```
if ('prop' in $jQueryObject) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do in other way
}
```

For using different version of jQuery in same page, check my answer of this question.

[script reference causes conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961120/script-reference-causes-conflict)

Comment: It turns our the two scripts in the if statement were still causing issues. I moved them to separate files calling them with        .getScript