# Confilct between two JQUERY libraries

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying Google autocomplete with Jquery jquery-1.9.1.js & jquery-ui.js like:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Its working fine but when I include anothee jquery like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```

for ajax control on same page, get the error:
TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).result is not a function

Both files functionality, are working fine individually but jointly giving me the error.

Can we not use:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

&
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>` together.Plese help on this or do we have any other JS liabriary compatible.

Comment: remove jquery-1.2.6.js from your page

Comment: have a look at [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: If you have to use two versions of jQuery, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961120/script-reference-causes-conflict/8961203#8961203

Comment: Why on earth one needs 2 jquery includes on the same page?

Comment: @LShetty That could be different plugins depend on different versions of jQuery.